# Is there a tools option in VLC for macOS?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Is there a "tools" option on the macOS version of VLC? If there is, I can't seem to find it. I need to re-orient a video from horizontal to vertical in order to upload to Instagram. They are picky and won't accept a horizontal video.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Just so you know, I removed your personally identifiable information. You should not post your personal email on this site; nobody here will do a “back and forth” with you via email to solve your issue. Any issues that can be solved or addressed here will be addressed publicly on this question. I also removed your request for free software if VLC can’t do what you wish it to do since this site is not about software recommendations either. That said, hopefully someone can address your question as stated and perhaps help in the end.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, it's under Preferences > Show all > Video > Filters.
See my answer to the [same question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/461719/).